# Elevate is usually used with preposition to

Tags: phrasal-verbs

> The Governor administered the oath of office to the new Chief Justice,
>   who had served in the Bombay High Court. Justice Tahilramani's
>   appointment as the Chief Justice of the Madras High Court followed the
>   elevation of her predecessor, Indira Banerjee, (as a Supreme Court
>   judge).

Elevate someone to something is the correct phrasing but in this extract [elevate as is used] . So I am a bit confused over its usage.

Comment: But "elevate" as verb is not present in your text, isn't it? "Elevation" is a noun, the particle "of" is used to point who was "elevated to" Supreme Court Judge: Indira Banerjee.

Comment: Source please, ideally with a link/

Comment: https://www.thehindu.com/todays-paper/tahilramani-sworn-in-as-chief-justice-of-madras-hc/article24673825.ece

Answer (score 1):

> Elevation of X to Y

lets us know explicitly who or what was raised, namely X, and what level was attained by the raising, namely Y.

Either the "of X" or the "to Y" can be omitted if X or Y are obvious from context.

In this case, it looks as though someone initially wrote "the elevation of her predecessor, Indira Banerjee" without specifying the level of elevation because the writer assumed the reader would have that knowledge. That is good grammar, but may be an unsafe assumption. It then looks as though someone edited the original prose to clarify the meaning, but the edit, perhaps an over-hasty edit as happens in the hurry of going to press, was ungrammatical.

> She was elevated as a Supreme Court Justice

seems to imply that she was elevated to something unspecified due to her being a Supreme Court Justice, which is not, I suspect, what was intended at all. "Elevated as" has a rather specialized meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Given *elevation*:

- *to X* answers the question *what/where is the target location of the elevation*, and
- *of X* answers the question *who is the owner of the elevation*.

You can actually use both *to X* and *of X* for *elevation* at the same time with no problems.

> The elevation of the platform to the 5th floor is completed.
>
> The elevation of John to a management position caused us to stop being friends.

---

*Elevation* is a *noun*.

*X elevates of Y*--verb usage--this would be clunky sounding and you shouldn't use this.

It would likely be interpreted somewhat like below, and leaves open the question *X elevates Y to what/where?*

> The promotion elevated me of status (bad).
>
> My status was elevated by the promotion (good).

*X elevates to Y* simply means X moves upward to the location Y.